# what i must change that i can read the pixel value from the array?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following  code. I read from the image a block of pixels and I would like to get the value from every block (array 16*16).
However, I get this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211)
>
> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file C:\opencv231\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 537

What should I change so that I can run my code ?

```
enum Color {White, Black}; 
Color checkBlock(Mat& img, int& i, int& j, double& T)
{
    unsigned int Sum=0;
    for(int k=0;k<16;k++)
        for(int l=0;l<16;l++)
            Sum += img.at<unsigned char>(i+k,j+l);
    double Average = Sum/256;
    std::cout << Average << std::endl;
    return (Average > T) ? (White) : (Black);
}

void main()
{
    Mat img = imread("Frame.jpg",0);
    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_NORMAL );// Create a window for display.
    if(!img.data)   
        std::cout << "error";
    // STEPS TO CONVERT TO BINARY IMAGE
    // LOAD THE IMAGE 
    cv::Mat imageMat = cv::imread("Frame.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    cv::Mat grayscaleMat (imageMat.size(), CV_8U);

    //Convert BGR to Gray
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayscaleMat, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    //Binary image
    cv::Mat binaryMat(grayscaleMat.size(), grayscaleMat.type());

    //Apply thresholding
    cv::threshold(grayscaleMat, binaryMat, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    //Show the results
    // cv::namedWindow("Output",CV_NORMAL);
    //cv::imshow("Output", binaryMat);

    // cv::waitKey(0);

    double minVal, maxVal;
    minMaxLoc(img,&minVal,&maxVal,NULL,NULL);
    double Threshold = 0.5 * (minVal + maxVal);
    int i=4,j=4;
    Size s = img.size();
    Color old_c, new_c;
    // define the position wher i will begin to read the first row from the image 
    for (j=16*55;j<=s.height;j=j+16)
        for(i=0;i<=s.width;i=i+16)
        {
            Point x(i,j);
            Point y(i+16,j+16);
            //std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
            rectangle(img, x, y, Scalar(255,0,0),3);
            Color c = checkBlock(img,i,j,Threshold);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are using `i` to index a row:

```
        Sum += img.at<unsigned char>(i+k,j+l);
```

But here, where `i` comes from, it is clearly the index of a col.

```
        for(i=0;i<=s.width;i=i+16)
```

So that first line should be:

```
Sum += img.at<unsigned char>(j+l, i+k);
```

Just to be clear, the arguments to `at` are (row, col), the paramters for Point are (x,y), which is a bit of a trap.

Also

```
for (j=16*55;j<=s.height;j=j+16)
    for(i=0;i<=s.width;i=i+16)
        ...
        Point y(i+16,j+16);
```

should be

```
for (j = 16 *  55; j < s.height - 15 ; j = j + 16)
    for(i = 0; i < s.width - 15; i = i + 16)
        ...
        Point y(i + 15, j + 15);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,i have change the place of (row,and col),the problem is that my code can read the first line to the end ,and then when he is finish with the last array(16*16) he stopped and dont move to the next row

Comment: I have updated my answer. It might be a good idea to learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The `imread()` must include the full path of your file, and be sure to use double dashes, e.g.

```
cv::Mat imageMat = cv::imread(C:\\Folder\\Frame.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

It is not necessary to specify the dimension or type of `grayscaleMat` or `binaryMat`, as the opencv functions will prepare them for you.

In your cvtColor function, it should be CV_RGB2GRAY not CV_BGR2GRAY.

In you threshold function, it should not be cv::THRESH_BINARY but rather CV_THRESH_BINARY

Hope this helps.

Comment: The exception is definitely in at<>(), and there is no need to provide the full path to the file, so long a whatever location you do provide is valid.

Comment: @B..., which location is does opencv look in by default?

Comment: It not so much where opencv looks, it;s where the C stio library looks. What even filename you provide ends up being passed to fopen(). So with no path that will be in the current work directory  or folder.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my case I usually keep videos in a separate folder on the desktop, therefore the path addition.